# Get current SDDL from AD Administrator

Tags: active-directory, powershell

due to the current proxylogon exploits I want to compare the difference on our AD Administrator account with the one from a Veeam AD Backup.

From the Veeam Backup I got a ntSecurityDescriptor string which I can import with ConvertFrom-SddlString command in Powershell.

But I see no way to get the current SDDL String from AD or a same output format like the one from ConvertFrom-SddlString.

Has someone a hint to compare the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint Ryan!

Based on this I was able to compare the objects with something like:

```
$oldSddl = "backupSDDLStringHere"
$oldSddlObject = ConvertFrom-SddlString -Type ActiveDirectoryRights $oldSddl
$dn = (Get-ADUser administrator).distinguishedName
$newSddl = (Get-Acl "AD:$dn").Sddl
$newSddlObject = ConvertFrom-SddlString -Type ActiveDirectoryRights $newSddl
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $oldSddlObject.DiscretionaryAcl -DifferenceObject $newSddlObject.DiscretionaryAcl
```

That seems to work and shows me the difference. And Ryan yes, the Sddl is different but it might be caused by the CU update.

Comment: You could check to see the last time AdminSDHolder was changed, also.

Answer (score 1):

[Get-Acl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl) has an `Sddl` property on the output and you can use it against AD objects like this:

```perl
$dn = (Get-ADUser administrator).distinguishedName
(Get-Acl "AD:$dn").Sddl
```

From there you could convert it with `ConvertFrom-SddlString` as well. But were I in your shoes, I'd just compare the raw Sddl strings first and only bother converting if they're different (assuming you know your backup value is "good").